# obtener los caracteres vecinos que no sean vocales

Tags: javascript

Quiero obtener los caracteres vecinos que no sean vocales, pero no me muestra todos, el codigo de abajo es lo que intente pero no cumple con mi objetivo.

```js
function solve(s) {
    s = s.split('');
    let res = '';
    let array = [];
    array = s.map((value, idx, arr) =>
        (!vocal(value) && !vocal(arr[idx - 1]) && typeof arr[idx - 1] !== 'undefined') ?
            res + value : res = ''
    )

    console.log(array);
    return 0;
};

function vocal(a) {
    let res = false;
    switch (a) {
        case 'a':
            res = true;
            break;
        case  'e':
            res = true;
            break;
        case  'i':
            res = true;
            break;
        case 'o':
            res = true;
            break;
        case 'u':
            res = true;
            break;
    }
    return res;
}

solve('hhollliillapiiii');
```

**resultado esperado:** [hh,lll,ll], el caracter **p** no tiene vecino que no sea vocal asi que no deberia entrar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [str.match(regexp)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) con una expresion regular para encontrar todas las subcadenas de minimo 2 caracteres no vocales:

```
/([^aeiou]{2,})/gi
```

Aunque si solo quieres letras tendrias que cambiar la expresion

```js
function solve(s) {
    array = s.match(/([^aeiou]{2,})/gi);
    console.log(array);
    return 0;
};

solve('hhollliillapiiii');
```

Comment: Vale la pena destacar que basta con la expresión regular; la función `vocal()` no se usa y se puede eliminar.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 2):

Lo más fácil es hacer un `replace` del string:

```
var s = 'hhollliillpiiii';
var sinvocales = s.replace(/[aeiouAEIOU]/g, '');
console.log(sinvocales); // imprime "hhlllllp"
```

Si lo que necesitás es un array de cada caracter, entonces:

```
var s = 'hhollliillpiiii';
var sinvocales = s.match(/[^aeiouAEIOU]/g);
console.log(sinvocales); // imprime ["h", "h", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "p"]
```

Comment: solve('hhollliillapiiii'); resultado esperado: [hh,lll,ll], el caracter p no tiene vecino que no sea vocal asi que no deberia entrar.

Comment: No entiendo, la *p* tiene vocal a la izquierda y a la derecha. ¿Cuál es la lógica que querés implementar, podrías ser un poco más específico?

Comment: sus vecinos deben ser NO vocales

Comment: O sea, si tengo un string como `apkl`, entonces `p` no cumple la condición porque tiene a su izquierda una vocal pero `k` y `l` si porque no tienen ninguna vocal. ¿Es esto lo que querés realizar?

Comment: en ese caso entraria pkl, pero si apkil el resultado seria pk

Answer (score 2):

Una solución usando expresiones regulares

```js
var cadena = 'hhollliillapiiii';
var salida = cadena.match(/(?![aeiou])([^aeiou])+([^aeiou])/g)
console.info(salida)
```